# Remember Facebook login Ionic

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a Facebook login in my app, but every time the app is closed and reopened, I need to log in again with Facebook.

How do I save the user's Facebook Login, so I do not have to click login again with Facebook, and just redirect to the home page?

My TS login is:

```
loginWithFB(userData) {


this.fb.login(['email', 'public_profile']).then((response: FacebookLoginResponse) => {
  this.fb.api('me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,picture.width(720).height(720).as(picture_small)', []).then(profile => {
    this.userData = { email: profile['email'], first_name: profile['first_name'], picture: profile['picture_small']['data']['url'], username: profile['name'] }

    if (this.userData != "") {

      this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage, { 'logfb': this.userData })

      this.events.publish('loginfacebook', this.userData, Date.now());
      //  this.navCtrl.push(HomePage, {
      //   'logfb': this.userData
      // });
    } else {
      let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({ duration: 3000, position: 'bottom' 
  });
      toast.setMessage('Não foi possível logar com Facebook');
      toast.present();
    }
  })

});
```

}

Comment: Where are you storing the resulting access token? Store that in persistent storage somewhere

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I did not understand your answer. My login code is just what I posted in my question. And when I log in to the Home Page, and send the profile photo and the name to the side menu

Answer (score 0):

Use localstorage for this so whenever you reload the page, the localstorage sees you logged in and stays logged in and whenever you want to logout use a button and empty the localstorage

Comment: But should I add to my Facebook login? I tried following the documentation, but no results.

Comment: yes look in the facebook docs. whenever the person logs in they will get a accessToken you have to store this somewhere to let the browser know the account is still active so save the token in the localstorage

Answer (score 0):

Use `Localstorage` plugin.

Call `loginWithFB()` from user login page. Inside that function set logged user to `localstorage`:

```
loginWithFB(userData) {
        this.fb.login(['email', 'public_profile']).then((response: FacebookLoginResponse) => {
                    this.fb.api('me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,picture.width(720).height(720).as(picture_small)', [])
                    .then(profile => {
                        this.userData = {
                            email: profile['email'],
                            first_name: profile['first_name'],
                            picture: profile['picture_small']['data']['url'],
                            username: profile['name']
                        }
                        // Set user to storage
                        this.nativeStorage.setItem('user', this.userData)
                    })
                    .then(() => { // Redirect to user page })
        // ....
```

Final step is to get user data when `platform is ready` from `localstorage`:

**Example:**

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Here we will check if the user is already logged in
      // because we don't want to ask users to log in each time they open the app
      let env = this;
      this.nativeStorage.getItem('user')
      .then( function (data) {
        // user is previously logged and we have his data
        // we will let him access the app
        env.nav.push(UserPage);
        env.splashScreen.hide();
      }, function (error) {
        //we don't have the user data so we will ask him to log in
        env.nav.push(LoginPage);
        env.splashScreen.hide();
      });
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
    });
```

This is very helpful link:
[Facebook Login](https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/facebook-authentication-in-ionic3-apps)